# Is it worth caching references to nested objects?

Tags: javascript, performance, caching, reference, nested

Let's say I have something like this:

```
var MyNamespace = {
    Presets: {
        Thing: {
            something: {
                rate: 10
            }
        }
    }
};
```

If I'm using `rate` in an `update()` function that fires hundreds of times a second, would it be better to cache the reference to the variable like this:

```
var rate = MyNamespace.Presets.Thing.something.rate;
function update() {
    var a = 5 + rate;
    console.log(a);
    return a;
}
```

Or I could just do:

```
function update() {
    var a = 5 + MyNamespace.Presets.Thing.something.rate;
    console.log(a);
    return a;
}
```

I suppose caching would be faster, but my question is whether it's fast *enough* to justify doing it. Would it be a micro optimization, or something I should be worrying about?

### Edit

To clarify:

1. I use [Phaser](http://phaser.io/).
2. `update()` is a member of a class.
3. Phaser uses [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) internally to update the game logic. When it does that, it calls my class' `update()`.

I made a [jsPerf test](https://jsperf.com/nested-objects-reference-caching). It showed no significant (or persistent) difference in:

- Firefox 51.0.0
- Chrome 56.0.2924
- Edge 14.14393.0
- IE 11.0.0

Sometimes it shows that the test without caching is a bit slower. But it's *sometimes*, it's not consistent, and it's not by much. I guess JavaScript optimizes stuff like that under the hood, though.

Comment: Optimizing: 1) only when it solves a problem (i.e. it's slow). 2) after having identifed the bottleneck 3) after having measured

Comment: Instead of worrying about such caching you would better care about encapsulation. `update` apparently should be a method/member, not function.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I am not asking whether I should optimize my code. I'm asking if the lack of caching is a possible problem. How could I identify the problem if I don't know what that problem could be?

Comment: @HristiyanDodov it's seems pretty easy to benchmark this to see if there's a significant difference between the two.

Comment: @hindmost `update()` _is_ a member in my actual code. I just wanted to give an easy example.

Comment: Then you probably have to post your actual code. Otherwise it looks like off-topic

Comment: @HristiyanDodov You don't have to ask when you can precisely measure. Have a look at the tools: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool

Comment: I know about these tools. I didn't use them because I wouldn't be able to spot a difference in my project where so much things happen, especially when the change is this small. I extremely simplified things and made a [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/nested-objects-reference-caching). It showed no significant difference across all my browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as a know, JavaScript always uses objects as references. this is why some JS-frameworks have clone-methods for objects, even for deep nested objects. In my opinion it is just a matter of taste or readability. Your first example is easier to read in my opinion.